# Issue with background check discrepancy and Interview/Resume and Layoff

Tags: job-offer

I have very strong and clean background in my job history until recently. 
I got laid off last Nov. I started searching new jobs since Jan.
Now I got the offer. During interview not much was asked about my last job from where I got laid off due to lack of work they had, but my previous experience was strongly matching with job requirement, however employer was not aware of my laid off and at the time I got offer, I have around 5 months of gap. Background check is about to start. I need advise as what should I do? 
Thanks

Comment: Advice on what to do regarding what? Mentioning being laid off? Omitting the job altogether?

Comment: Employment gaps are not a security violation unless you mislead about the gap.

Comment: I did not inform that I am being laid off. This is the concern what I have and it may appear in background check. Question is, is it the big issue for employer to withdraw job offer?

Comment: Is this in the US? Typically in the US "background check" refers to a criminal check to see that you've not had any major legal issues, so I am curious if it has a different meaning elsewhere.

Comment: What did you say when the new company asked "why did you leave company A"? Or did you give them the impression you were still working for company A when you interviewed with the new company?

Answer (score 5):

If you CV is accurate then no problem. Some people are unemployed for a period of time. People understand this.

If you lied on your CV then that is a different matter.

Comment: Ed; thanks for response. At the time they had my resume, it was not updated and was saying I was employee there. During interview, I did not surface up, neither I clarify since I was not being asked. I believe, I will specify on my background application, then there may be cross question from HR.

Comment: @user66757 Did you send them the resume before or after you were laid off? You should add this information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should have volunteered the information during the interview, or given them a more accurate resume.  "You didn't ask" isn't a good excuse for not conveying information which is relevant.  At that time you could have mentioned very casually that the problem which had caused you to start looking for other work (not having enough work at your current job) came to its inevitable conclusions, etc.  At that time, it wouldn't have been thought remarkable.

If there is some way you can matter-of-factly slip the information to them, in a casual conversation or an updated resume, you should be able to smooth this over.  It may be that they won't care one way or the other especially if you don't seem to be hiding it.

You could even have presented it as an advantage ("I just wanted to let you know I have been laid off earlier than I anticipated and I am available whenever you want me to start...").  However, the five month gap kind of shoots that down now.

If they turn up the lay-off during the background check and ask "why didn't you say anything at the interview?" you may be able to get away with "sorry, didn't realize you were working off an old resume."  I'd advise you to get your resume updated and put it out on linked-in or whatever sites you post your resume to, to make it obvious that you aren't trying to cover up your layoff...

Comment: Lying in interviewing or on your resume is always bad. Lying by omission is still lying. No company you would want to work for would care if you were laid off, only if you were fired for cause so it was unnecessary to lie in the first place. It would be deal breaker for most good companies to find out you lied.